# Choose a SQL table-valued function dynamically at runtime?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'll preface this with that I've recommended we instead **look at some sort of reporting software** that is outside the application, but, time being limited as is, I'm at my current question.

I'm building a function and would like to use parameter setting. How do I avoid the following?

```
//extremely dangerous
var queryString = "Select * from dbo." + functionName + "(:startDate, :endDate)";
var result = GetANHibernateSession().CreateSQLQuery(queryString)
                 .SetDateTime("startDate", startDate)
                 .SetDateTime("endDate", endDate);
```

The functions can come & go at runtime, meaning that I cannot build the queries at compile time.

EDIT: I should also point out that the functionName is not coming from an untrusted source, but within the database itself with no external facing insertion mechanism. This is only a small bit of security though.